# Can't sync filesystem without reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, hardware, synchronization

I'm having an issue with a linux server. Once a week the running mysql instance hangs and there is no way to fully stop it. If I kill it, it remains in zombie status and init does not reap its pid.

The server is used for staging deployments and some internal tools, so it's not under heavy load. The only process constantly used id mysql and for this I think that it's the only process which suffer of this issue.

I've searched system logs for errors and the only thing I found is this error (repeated a couple of times) in dmesg output:

```
[706560.640085] INFO: task mysqld:31965 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[706560.640198] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[706560.640312] mysqld          D ffff88032fd93f40     0 31965      1 0x00000000
[706560.640317]  ffff880242a27d18 0000000000000086 ffff88031a50dd00 ffff880242a27fd8
[706560.640321]  ffff880242a27fd8 ffff880242a27fd8 ffff88031e549740 ffff88031a50dd00
[706560.640325]  ffff88031a50dd00 ffff88032fd947f8 0000000000000002 ffffffff8112f250
[706560.640328] Call Trace:
[706560.640338]  [<ffffffff8112f250>] ? __lock_page+0x70/0x70
[706560.640344]  [<ffffffff816cb1b9>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[706560.640347]  [<ffffffff816cb28f>] io_schedule+0x8f/0xd0
[706560.640350]  [<ffffffff8112f25e>] sleep_on_page+0xe/0x20
[706560.640353]  [<ffffffff816c9900>] __wait_on_bit+0x60/0x90
[706560.640356]  [<ffffffff8112f390>] wait_on_page_bit+0x80/0x90
[706560.640360]  [<ffffffff8107dce0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x40/0x40
[706560.640363]  [<ffffffff8112f891>] filemap_fdatawait_range+0x101/0x190
[706560.640366]  [<ffffffff81130975>] filemap_write_and_wait_range+0x65/0x70
[706560.640371]  [<ffffffff8122e441>] ext4_sync_file+0x71/0x320
[706560.640376]  [<ffffffff811c3e6d>] do_fsync+0x5d/0x90
[706560.640379]  [<ffffffff811c40d0>] sys_fsync+0x10/0x20
[706560.640383]  [<ffffffff816d495d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

When this happens the only way to make everything working again is a full reboot, but in order to do that I'm forced to use this command after I've manually stopped all running processes

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

otherwise normal reboot process hangs forever. I've tracked reboots script and I've found out that also the reboot process hangs on a sync call, this one in `/etc/init.d/sendsigs` (I'm on ubuntu)

```
# Flush the kernel I/O buffer before we start to kill
# processes, to make sure the IO of already stopped services to
# not slow down the remaining processes to a point where they
# are accidentily killed with SIGKILL because they did not
# manage to shut down in time.
sync
```

I'm almost sure that the cause of this is an hardware issue (the RAID controller???) also because I've other two machines with the same hardware and software configuration and they don't suffer of this, but I can't find any hint in syslog or dmesg. I've also installed smartmontools and mcelog packages but none of them did report any issue.

What can I do to track the cause of this issue?

Today is happened again, here is the status of system after triggering a reboot

```
init─┬─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-dae}]
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─mcelog
     ├─mysqld───{mysqld}
     ├─newrelic-daemon───newrelic-daemon───11*[{newrelic-daemon}]
     ├─ntpd
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─python3
     ├─rpc.idmapd
     ├─rpc.statd
     ├─rpcbind
     ├─sh───rc───S20sendsigs───sync
     ├─smartd
     ├─snmpd
     ├─sshd───sshd───zsh───sudo───zsh───pstree
     └─sshd───sshd───zsh───sudo───zsh
```

And here is the status of sync process

```
# ps aux | grep sync
root      3637  0.1  0.0   4352   372 ?        D    05:53   0:00 sync
```

i.e. Uninterruptible sleep...

#### Hardware specs as reported by `lshw`

I think the raid controller is a fake raid. I usually don't deal with hardware (and for the record I don't have physical access to it)

```
description: Computer
product: X7DBP ()
vendor: Supermicro
version: 0123456789
serial: 0123456789
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=disabled uuid=53D19F64-D663-A017-8922-0030487C1FEE
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: X7DBP
   vendor: Supermicro
   physical id: 0
   version: PCB Version
   serial: 0123456789
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Phoenix Technologies LTD
      physical id: 0
      version: 6.00
      date: 05/29/2007
      size: 106KiB
      capacity: 960KiB
      capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy2880 acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification

  *-storage
         description: RAID bus controller
         product: 631xESB/632xESB SATA RAID Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 09
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:19 ioport:18a0(size=8) ioport:1874(size=4) ioport:1878(size=8) ioport:1870(size=4) ioport:1880(size=32) memory:d8500400-d85007ff
```

Comment: Looks like Intel fakeraid. Run `smartctl -a /dev/sd*` on all the individual disks and pastebin them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton done, here's the link http://pastebin.com/hZwACcxv

Comment: Wow, they're RE drives. That's a surprise.

Comment: As I told you I don't often deal with hardware, I assume from your comment that they are good drives.

Comment: Did you check to see if there's a firmware update for the controller? I had this issue once with an HP server (except *anything* could cause the I/O hang) and an update cleared it up.

Comment: @NathanC I've checked the mainboard manifacturer website (since it's a fakeraid controller) and they only offers exe download for flashing BIOS. Further I don't have physical access to the machine. I might ask tech support if they can do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your process state is `D`, which technically means uninterruptible sleep. Though, as I always say, `D` means Disk. Processes in this state are waiting for a disk I/O operation to complete.

We can see from your call trace that `mysqld` itself was trying to `sync` and got stuck for more than 120 seconds waiting for the sync to complete.

This indicates that something is wrong with your storage subsystem. You should look at your hard disks and disk controller (if local disks) or network and SAN (if remote storage).

Comment: Yes, that's what I've imagined. However I'd need a way to identify which hardware component is failing, I can't ask a full server replacement to support guys. I've already tried with smartmontools and mcelog to identify the hardware component that's failing but none of them report anything. Moreover the server has 4 disks in raid 5 for this reason I'd assume that if a single disk is failing the raid controller should handle this and does not hang.